# Cannot transfer or delete app (iTunes Connect)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

I want to transfer my app to the client's account, so that it's published under their name. Dev and testing was done under my account. As far as I can see, I've satisfied all of the criteria needed before transferring (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html), but the transfer or delete link is not visible - no entitlements have been added. This is an Ionic app - although this should make no difference, I have seen warnings recently about push notification entitlement (we don't use these, or have the module enabled, and appears to be a recent Cordova issue).

I had set Internal testing to "Not available for Testing" (no effect), and have now deleted all internal testers from the app (also no effect).

Although we did not go through the External testing stage, just to see if that was mandatory, I set myself up as an external tester and then set it to "Not available for Testing".

I tried taking it out of "Prepare for Submission" status, and did a dummy submit so that it's now in "Developer Rejected" status - still no transfer or delete link.

Does anyone know how to get this to work

[App Information page screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZtrN.png)

Comment: Has the app ever been published? If not, don't transfer it, create a new record in the target Member Center + iTunes Connect, and submit it there directly. What's the point of transferring it?

Comment: It's not been published, no. Although the client has added my login to their provider account, so I can see their account in xcode, itunes connect won't allow me to create a new target in their account (complaining an app with the same name exists). If I try and publish through my account to their account, itunes complains that "Your user account is attached to several iTunes providers. Create separate accounts for each provider before logging in."

Comment: btw, why was the question downgraded?

Comment: Change the name of the previous app to something random to avoid the name conflict. Or pick UK English instead of English as the primary language. You should use a dedicated Apple ID for each iTunes Connect account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this is likely caused by the fact that your app is not in one of the states that are necessary to transfer the app. However as one of the comments pointed out, to fix this you can simply change the name of you rapp, add letters or numbers to it or delete the record of it entirely, through the link you have already found. Then, once the name is available follow the steps you took to create the app again in the new iTunes Connect account (the Client's) and create the app with the proper name there. Then once this is finished simply upload a new `.ipa` file via Application loader or build using the latest Xcode and you should be good to go!
 Hope that helps, Julian Engel

Comment: as both yourself and jcaron said - the solution was to change the name of the dev instance in itunes connect. That allowed me perform a new upload under the client's team login. Thanks to both of you for answering.